# Table Rates percentage of subtotal (Magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way to use table rates in Magento that set the rate at a percentage of subtotal?

Or is there a way to set a range of subtotals that are at different percentage rates for shipping?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try quick method then copy Tablerate.php from app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php to local directory , then make changes in the file. Around line no 126
you can see code like

```
$shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']/100);
```

change the code to

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
$shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($subtotal*$rate['price']/100);
```

Then upload csv file for different rates for table rate shipping in the config then it will work. You can try sample csv as follow

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
*,*,*,1,25
*,*,*,100,20
*,*,*,150,15
*,*,*,200,10
*,*,*,250,5
```

Above csv contain different rates and the change code above changes it to percent calculation of the shipping.

Answer (score 0):

On the latter, you would need to develop your own shipping module for this, perhaps forked off of one of the existing shipping modules. It's actually one of the more documented projects you can undertake in Magento. For instance, take a look at [the Magento site's tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe